# TSQL Select runs even within IF statement that does not execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Final Edit;
Got it working by updating

```
IF @@servername = 'Production'
```

to

```
IF ServerProperty('ServerName')  = 'Production'
```

Thanks shawnt00 for stepping through this!

---

I have a peculiar issue where in test the database names are suffixed with test but in live they do not exist.

So when testing to release code to production I have to write an if statement that states if am on test, use the test database otherwise use the production database. As shown below.

However, the issue seems that even if I am on Test, the select statement for the production database still runs and throws an error due to the Database not existing on test, only DatabaseTest does.

On Test @@servername will be 'Test'. On prod, it will be 'Production'.

```
DECLARE @serverName VARCHAR(50)= @@servername;
DECLARE @WhoModified VARCHAR(30)= 'Me';
DECLARE @DateModified DATETIME= GETDATE();
DECLARE @StatusNameCancel VARCHAR(30)= 'Cancelled';
DECLARE @StatusCodeCancel INT= 0;


IF @@servername = 'Production'
BEGIN;
    SELECT @StatusCodeCancel = Value
    FROM DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
    WHERE ParameterName = @StatusNameCancel;

    UPDATE [DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableB]
      SET
          StatusCode = @StatusCodeCancel,
          WhoModified = @WhoModified,
          WhenModified = @DateModified
    WHERE ID IN(1, 2);
END;

IF @@servername = 'Test'
BEGIN

    SELECT @StatusCodeCancel = ParameterValue
    FROM DatabaseATest.dbo.TableA
    WHERE ParameterName = @StatusNameCancel;

    UPDATE [DatabaseATest].[dbo].[TableB]
      SET
          StatusCode = @StatusCodeCancel,
          WhoModified = @WhoModified,
          WhenModified = @DateModified
     WHERE ID IN(1, 2);
END;
```

Is there any workaround to this?

[image]

Comment: `select @@servername` shows what?

Comment: When Im on test, @@servername shows the name of the 'Test' database. I even added a print statement and commented out the Select statement under the production statement and it runs fine when that is done. Once I add the select statement back in with the Database name that isn't in the environment, it throws the exception.

Comment: Try removing the semicolons after `begin`. It shouldn't be the problem but it's not exactly common to include those either.

Comment: @shawnt00 it still errors with or without the semi colons. Thankfully, for this specific case, the data I am selecting between Live and test is the exact same, so I can get around this issue by statically setting my StatusCodeCancel variable to the value I need, however, if the data was different across environments I would be quite stuck.

Comment: Not buying as I test this and it works fine me.

Comment: Screenshot would probably be nice. If not that then report the full error message. Also try `SELECT ServerProperty('machinename') as [machinename], ServerProperty('ServerName') as [ServerName], @@ServerName as [@@ServerName];`

Comment: @shawnt00 added screenshot of full sql + error message.

Comment: That error line is in the test section.

Comment: It's also errors about column names rather than "invalid object name".

Comment: another interesting find, on test, there is the TableTest Database, but also a Database with the same name as whats on production. There is also a table thats the same as prod but the column names are different. So the 'Production' SQL statement can run on test or prod, however on test the column names are fsParamName and fsParamValue instead.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only batch of code that's running? What about dynamic sql?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn about dynamic SQL. So much easier to manage and control.

Comment: @shawnt00 i got it working thanks to your replay regarding server property I'll update OP with the fix. if you make that comment into an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double-check the server name. Make sure these values all look right:

```
SELECT
    ServerProperty('machinename') as [machinename], 
    ServerProperty('ServerName') as [ServerName],
    @@ServerName as [@@ServerName];
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql